# Remove a contact from contact groups in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

Recently a colleague resigned from our company and I need to delete her from
 *all the contact groups* in my Outlook.
Any suggest will be appreciated!
 **Is there a easily way to do this?**

Comment: This may help, (you could of added the outlook version, etc)

Comment: hope this helps(You could have added the outlook version, etc)If you wish delete contacts in your group or in your contact list, please follow these steps:
To delete contacts in a group: 
1. Sign into http://people.live.com
2. Type the group name on the texbox under All.
3. Click the group name.
4. Click Edit on the Orange bar.
5. Click the X button on the contact that you want to remove.
6. Click Save.

To delete contacts in contact list:
1. Sign into http://people.live.com
2. Click the checkbox of the contact/s that you want to delete.
3. Click Delete twice.
sorry took too long.

Comment: I'm using outlook2010(32bit), and Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting one contact from all groups requires a VBA macro.

Such a macro is detailed in the article
[How to Quickly Remove a Specific Contact from All Contact Groups via Outlook VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/quickly-remove-specific-contact-contact-groups-via-outlook-vba/).

The article details how such a macro is installed via the
Developer tab / Visual Basic, and can later be run via the
Run icon in the toolbar.

In case that article later disappears, the VBA macro is detailed here :

```
Sub RemoveSpecificContactfromAllGroups()
    Dim strSpecificContact As String
    Dim objTempMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.recipient
    Dim objContactsFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objContactGroup As Outlook.DistListItem
    Dim objContact As Outlook.ContactItem
    Dim nprompt As Integer

    strSpecificContact = InputBox("Input the fullname or email address of the specific contact to be removed from all contact groups:")
    Set objTempMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set objRecipient = objTempMail.Recipients.Add(strSpecificContact)
    objRecipient.Resolve

    If objRecipient.Resolved = True Then
       Set objContactsFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
       For Each objItem In objContactsFolder.Items
           If TypeOf objItem Is DistListItem Then
              Set objContactGroup = objItem
              With objContactGroup
                   .RemoveMember objRecipient
                   .Body = "Contact Removed: " & strSpecificContact & vbTab & "(" & Now & ")" & .Body
                   .Save
              End With
           End If
       Next
       nprompt = MsgBox("Removing Completes!", vbExclamation, "Remove Contact from Group")
    Else
       nprompt = MsgBox("This contact cannot be resolved!", vbExclamation, "Resolving Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi，harrymc, it really helps a lot, thank you !